# c# if or logic comparison

Tags: c#, if-statement

Can someone explain the logic of the ifs with || in c# because at the moment all three ifs execute

```
     string bla = "0";
        if (bla != "0" || bla != "")
        {
           //
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        if (bla != "0" | bla != "")
        {
            //
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        if (bla == "0" || bla == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            //
        }
```

Comment: I would prefer it if you explained in detail what each statement does, what it evaluates to, what you expected it to evaluate to and why you expected this. That would be great.

Comment: All three execute because they are all three true.  If you only want the first matching `if` to execute, then use `else if` instead for the second and third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the 'OR' operator.  Only one condition needs to be true for the if to execute.

By replacing the variable and reading "out loud" you get the following:

#1  if "0" != "0"  OR  "0" != ""  in this case it is true that "0" != ""

#2  if "0" != "0" | "0" != ""   in this case you have false | true (bitwise) which equals true

#3 if "0" == "0" OR "0" == ""  in this case "0" == "0" is true so the entire condition is true.

You might try these with the && (AND) operator to compare the difference.

Comment: Thanks && is what I am looking for, I am being an idiot

Answer (score 3):

- The first one says: bla is not "0" OR **bla is not an empty string**.
- The second one says: bla is not "0" [bitwise] OR **bla is not an empty string**.
- The third one says: **bla is "0"** or bla is an empty string

The bolded parts are what cause the IF condition to pass.

I won't explain bitwise operators in depth, but what you need to know here is that it will execute the 2nd part even if the 1st part is truthy (i.e. it's *not* lazy like logical operators).

Answer (score 1):

All ifs are true because || and | are or operators and bla can't be equal to zero and and empty string at the same time. This means that one of the or clauses always evaluates to true and this results in all if statements executing.

Did you want to use the && (and) operator instead ?

Answer (score 0):

`||` is an alternative which derives from the bascics mathematics. It can be understood as `OR` connective, If we have given at least two logic formulas p,q, then following table applies. 1 is true 0 i false.

```
p | q |  p || q
0 | 0 |    0
0 | 1 |    1
1 | 0 |    1
1 | 1 |    1
```

The logical expression in any conditional instruction is evaluated by the logical rules known from mathematics.

**Before** asking more questions you should learn about: conjunction `&&`, alternative `||` , exclusive alternative `^` and unary operator negation `!` also you should learn about lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

|| in ifs means "or" condition, so in your code each if will be execute when bla equals to "0" or when bla equals to "". You have three if equal so they will be execute because bla equal to "0".

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `||` and `|`, is that with logical Or (`||`), if the first operand evaluates to True, the second one is not evaluated. With bitwise Or (`|`), both are always evaluated. The outcome in your case is the same.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The way these are compared is like this:

With the "*or*" (`||`) comparator, if one or both are true, the whole comparison will be true. i.e.

```
true || false = true
true || true = true
false || false = false
```

So because in all three, one of the comparisons is true, all 3 execute

The opposite side of the coin: *and* (`&&`) works the opposite way

```
true && false = false
false && false = false
true && true = true
```